# Calculating share of data.frame row pairs that match

Tags: r

I have a dataset with an id variable and several other variables, similar to this:

```
mydata <- tibble::tribble(
  ~idvar, ~age,
  1, 18,
  1, 18,
  2, 27,
  3, 89,
  4, 89,
  5, 12,
  1, 17,
  2, 27,
  2, 28,
  3, 41
)
```

For each value of `idvar`, I want to calculate the rate at which, given `idvar` is the same between a pair of rows, age is also the same. In other words, I want to know:

```
PR(age match | id match)
```

For example, there are three rows with `idvar == 1`, which form three pairs of rows. For one of those pairs, age also matches. So we would return .333 for `idvar == 1`.

Desired output:

```
1 .333
2 .333
3 0
4 NA
5 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `table` from base R. From the manual for `?base::table`:

> `table` uses the cross-classifying factors to build a contingency table of the counts at each combination of factor levels.

In other words, we can use it to count the number of entries for each unique value of `age`. Where the count is more than 1, we know we have a match (or repeated value) somewhere in `age`.

```
table(mydata$age)

12 17 18 27 28 41 89 
 1  1  2  2  1  1  2
```

For your given example, we will not do this for all of `age` at once. Instead, we will need to group by `idvar` first.

Additionally, we need to use the binomial coefficient on each element of `table(age)` to determine how many pairs are possible, and then sum them all up to get the total number of pairs in the numerator. In R, the `choose(n,k)` function is the binomial coefficient. The denominator is just `choose(.N, 2)` (in `data.table`, `.N` is the number of rows in the current group), which is the number of all possible pairs for the group.

Putting it all together:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)

# Helper function
count_pairs <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) > 1) {                           # if more than 1 row
    if (length(table(x)[table(x) > 1]) > 0) {    # if there is at least 1 match
      sum(sapply(table(x)[table(x) > 1], function(z) choose(z, 2)))
    } else {
      0                                          # no matches
    }
  } else {
    NA_real_                                     # only 1 row
  }
}

mydata[, count_pairs(age) / choose(.N, 2), by = idvar]
```

```
   idvar        V1
1:     1 0.3333333
2:     2 0.3333333
3:     3 0.0000000
4:     4        NA
5:     5        NA
```